# Automatically sort data-bound pivot table in two dimensions in Excel 2007 using VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel

Here's an annoying issue. I've got a pivot table in an Excel spreadsheet which gets its data direct from a SQL server query.

The table has customers on the vertical axis, and dates on the horizontal access. Both need to be correctly sorted - i.e. customers as alphabetical top to bottom and dates in date order from left to right.

I've ensured that the data coming out of SQL is recognised by EXcel as a date field. You can sort the dates successfully using the manual A-Z function. But I need to do it automatically using VBA.

I had hoped (againt hope) that using two sorting parameters on the SQL query might do the trick:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM myView ORDER BY Customer, Date"

Set pt = Worksheets("MyReport").PivotTables("MyPivot")
pt.PivotCache.CommandText = sql
pt.RefreshTable
```

But it doesn't.

I see than in Excel 2010 onwards there's a handy AutoSort function that should do what I need. But I'm stuck with 2007. Is there a way to sort my data in both dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there is an AutoSort feature in Excel 2007, but it belongs to the PivotFields object, rather than the pivot table itself.

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Set pt = Worksheets("myWorksheet").PivotTables("myPivotTable")
pt.PivotFields("DATE").AutoSort xlAscending, "DATE"
```